# Parse.com: unable to get recently created objectid in parse javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to save a record then getting new created objectId.I am using following Code.

```
     var query = new Parse.Query("Inspection");
     var Inspection = new Parse.Object("Inspection"); 
        query.include('property');
        query.equalTo("property", { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "Property",  "objectId": propertyId});
        query.first({
          success: function(inspectionData) {

    Inspection.set("companyAddress", inspectionData.get("companyAddress"));
    Inspection.set("companyLogo", inspectionData.get("companyLogo"));
    Inspection.set("tenantPhone", inspectionData.get("tenantPhone"));
    Inspection.save().then(function(Inspection) {
         console.log("in success");
         console.log(Inspection);
         console.log(Inspection.id);
    },
    function(error) {
         console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
},
          error: function(error) {
            console.log('in error')
             console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
           }
         });
```

But new record inserted and i did not get the console.log of "in success" and object id.
What i am doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the query returning any values?

Comment: This query is returning values (that is fine) but after saving the record i am not getting recently inserted objectId.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the proper syntax for creating a new object something like this?

```
var InspectionClass = Parse.Object.extend("Inspection");
var Inspection = new InspectionClass();
```

Or even better, using Backbone Syntax :

```
var inspection = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "Inspection",
    companyAddress: inspectionData.get("companyAddress"),
    companyLogo: inspectionData.get("companyLogo"),
    tenantPhone: inspectionData.get("tenantPhone")
});
```

Comment: I have already created a class name with inspection and i try your suggested code but it is not working..Actually what i am doing is that first i am trying to fetch a record then try to save a record record using that data.